# not getting options like choosing info in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

hi i have been using android studio for some time now and i am not able to acces logcat properly as i am not able to choose info or verbose etc not getting option to do so can anyone help to solve this problem ? so that logcat can work properly

i tried to look at stack overflow but that didnt help as i am not getting option of seeing info as you can see in image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After update the logcat was changed

Do this step for old Logcat window

```
File -> Settings -> Experimental
```

Turn off this check

[image: Turn off to this new logcat window]